# It's not need encoding/decoding to communicate system using other UNICODE encoding?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, decoding, utf-32

I just wonder.

When two system use other Unicode encoding (one-UTF-8, other-UTF32), it doesn't need to encode or decode?

I think it's necessary. But, we call just UNICODE in visual studio.
Then, If it's necessary (other application should encode or decode), it is not standard. Isn't it?

Comment: Of course you have to encode and decode.  UTFs are standardized byte encodings of Unicode. UTF-8 is encoded differently than UTF-32 (and UTF-16, which is what Windows uses for Unicode).  So UTF-8/16 data must be decoded if it needs to be processed as UTF-32, and vice versa for encoding.  Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I thought like that because visual studio just define UNICODE or else. I thought visual studio need to define each encoding type. um... after saw your comment, I realized. IDE doesn't need to consider other encoding type. just need OS encoding, supporting encoding type.
Again thanks a lot for reading my terrible English writting.